# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Woocommerce

Tags: angularjs, api, woocommerce, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am trying to use Woocommerce API for my mobile application but I am getting the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.weburl.com/wc-api/v3/?consumer_key=ck_ckcomeshere&consumer_secret=cs_cscomeshere. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.105:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How do I resolve this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although not highly secure but this did the trick. Add the following line to your `.htaccess` or your `apache.conf` file.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```